# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mpcstech_expense_db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector


conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                               
                               database='mpcstech_expense_db',
                               user='mpcstech_expense_db',
                               password='ABCABC')
if conn.is_connected():
    print('Connected to MySQL database')
```

I have written this code i am not able to connect with my databse on my website portal. if i try with user="root", password="", database="xyz",host="localhost" using XAMPP i am able to connect. But i want to connect and send data to my hosted website using Python and i am facing Below error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nspat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 323, in _open_connection
self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'mpcstech_expense_db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\nspat\Desktop\Final Project\testing_database.py", line 4, in 
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
File "C:\Users\nspat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 322, in connect
return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\nspat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 140, in **init**
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\nspat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1363, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "C:\Users\nspat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 328, in _open_connection
raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mpcstech_expense_db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user in MySQL, you need grant privileges to the user in order to define the actions the user can perform on specific databases and tables. If you do not, your account would be blocked from accessing to the database you want.

For example, if you would like to allow the user to access and perform `SELECT` on `mpcstech_expense_db`, this is what you should do:

1. Log in to MySQL with root or any other accounts that are allowed to grant certain privileges you would like to grant to the user account you have created.
2. `GRANT SELECT ON mpcstech_expense_db.* TO "mpcstech_expense_db"@"localhost"`